# source() fails to find file names

Tags: r, function, rstudio, package

When I try to run an R code, it says the below:

```
> source("General_functions.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'General_functions.R': No such file or directory
> source("function.R")
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'function.R': No such file or directory
```

When I try to install ANY packages, it says "available.packages" is not available. That means i cannot run anything?

Thank you!

I re-installed R and still didn't help.

Comment: Did you set your working directory with `setwd()`?

Comment: Some context on the package installation problem would help. What code are you running?

Comment: > install.packages("sqldf")
    Error in install.packages : could not find function "available.packages"

Comment: please? no response?

Comment: Start a new R session ("clean", if possible, i.e. with `--vanilla`) and add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question (by editing it). Also, you are asking two different questions: 1. "why can't I `source()`?" A: most likely you have the wrong working directory. 2. "why can't I install packages/find `available.packages()`?" A: we don't know, you haven't given us enough information yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your `source` commands are failing because R/RStudio cannot find the requested files ("General_functions.R" and "functions.R"). This is likely because you are using relative paths, but have not set the working directory appropriately. Use `setwd()` to point R/RStudio at the directory that contains these files.

Comment: Then why can't I install any packages whatsoever either?

Comment: like literally available.packages function is also missing

Comment: Hard to say without much more information about your installation. Is your copy of RStudio loading the `utils` package, which contains `available.packages`?

Comment: @hippie_poe You don't install packages with available.packages. You also didn't show us anything in your code that shows us that available.packages is missing for you.

Comment: > install.packages("sqldf")
    Error in install.packages : could not find function "available.packages"

Comment: please? no response?